# visual studio 2008 not responding when checking out items from source safe

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I have an interesting problem. whenever I try to check out items from source safe through VS 08 interface, the app stops responding.

A weird thing is, I can check out project items from the business layer but not the website items from the web layer.

I'm having to manually check them in/out from source safe. I know this isn't much info, if there is anything else you can think of that I need to do or list, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio 2008 with SourceSafe at my workplace and I get a momentary lag whilst trying get the latest on the entire solution.

Checking out individual files isn't instantaneous, but the lag isn't that noticable really.

Have you considered the move to use Subversion instead of Visual SourceSafe?  The Visual Studio plug-in interface, either [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) or [AnhkSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=3794), is very similar to that of the SourceSafe plug-in but you can also use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to get to the files under source-control directly, much in the same way as you're currently using the SourceSafe UI.

Comment: it is definitely not lag. i can check out files that are not part of the web project. the issue is also more than just checking out, it is any interaction with VSS (get latest version, add/removing files) that causes VS to not respond.

i would love to use another source control besides VSS (which i've always disliked and now hate), unfortunately our company will not change.

Comment: Well, put the lag times in terms of $$ & show them the savings in time & money. I am sure they will oblige.